# How to fetch trending hashtags from Twitter and display on web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am new to `HTML` and web development. I would like to work on mini project, where I can fetch the top 10 latest trending hashtags from `Twitter` and display it on the Web page. For this I have below code. I know it's not a good idea to add API key directly into JavaScript for security reasons, but for test purpose I wanted to see if I can at least fetch the data. When I ran below code, I am only seeing my heading tag and not the fetched hashtags. Am I missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Trending Hashtags</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Trending Hashtags</h1>
  <ul id="hashtags-list"></ul>

  <script>
    // Fetch the trending hashtags from Twitter
    fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer API KEY',
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const hashtagsList = document.getElementById('hashtags-list');

        // Iterate over the hashtags and create list items
        data[0].trends.forEach(hashtag => {
          const listItem = document.createElement('li');
          listItem.textContent = `#${hashtag.name}`;
          hashtagsList.appendChild(listItem);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```